# kafka streams in runtime change in/out topics

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

How to add an incoming topic and change an outgoing topic while the application is running? Depending on which incoming topic is currently being worked with, the outgoing topic should change.

in_topic1 -> filter OK -> out_topic1;
in_topic2 -> filter OK -> out_topic2.

```
final Serde<byte[]> byteArraySerde = Serdes.ByteArray();
    final Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();
    final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
    
    final KStream<byte[], String> textLines = builder
       .stream(prop.getProperty("kafka.topic.in"), Consumed.with(byteArraySerde, stringSerde));
    
    final KStream<byte[], String> processed = textLines
       .filter(MetaModelProcessor.filter())
       .mapValues(MetaModelProcessor.getMetaModel());
    processed.to(prop.getProperty("kafka.topic.out"));
    
    final org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams streams = new org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams(builder.build(), new KafkaStreamsConfig(prop.getProperty("kafka.app.id.config"), prop.getProperty("kafka.client.id.config"), prop.getProperty("kafka.server")).getStreamsConfiguration());
    
    streams.cleanUp();
    streams.start();
    
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));
```

Answer (score 0):

A Kafka stream application is basically a wrapper over a Producer and Consumer with higher order transformation functions. When you create a Streams application, you are initializing a topology that interacts with the broker. Adding dynamic ingress and egress topics is not a trivial operation.

What would happen to the intermediately processed results of a `v1` topology that consumed a message from topic `I1` and was just about to write to topic `T1` when a dynamic event switches the output topic to `T2`. Worse, what if there's a state store being maintained.

This seems to be a weird requirement. If you are finding yourself in this place, it probably means we need to revisit the use case and the design thoroughly.